# Accessing value of the div tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a following HTML structure:

```
    <div class="swiper-container2">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>January</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>February</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>March</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>April</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>May</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>June</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>July</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>August</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>September</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>October</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>November</h3></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><h3>December</h3></div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- Add Pagination -->

                        <!-- Add Arrows -->
                        <div id="swiperNext" class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                        <div id="swiperPrevious" class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    </div>
```

The above is a list of months that I load into my slider, which acts as a swiper. And these are swiper buttons (which are  basically div tags):

```
   <div id="swiperNext" class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div id="swiperPrevious" class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
```

And I've created on click events on them in jquery like following:

```
 $('#swiperNext').click(function(e)
   {
      alert('Next button pressed');
   });
   $('#swiperPrevious').click(function(e)
   {
       alert('Previous button pressed');
   });
```

Now I'm supposed to pick up the current value inside the slider (month name) and pass the value from the slider into the JS onclick function, which will then be passed into my my PHP funciton ...  Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please do elaborate what your question is, "Do something with it" is **NOT** a proper question description.

Comment: Hi I've edited the question, can you look into it now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in the docs:
`swiper-slide-active` is the currently active element's classname, so:

`$('.swiper-slide-active').html()` is NOT working

but `$('.swiper-slide-active h3').html()` does work.

( http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.V0f-6L52OPs )

Comment: But I don't use this class at all... Where am I supposed to use it to get the values that I need?

Comment: The slider itself uses this for the centered element. You can use it anywhere if there is a slider.

Comment: I've tried it like this:    $('#swiperNext').click(function(e)
   {
       $('.swiper-slide-active').html();
   }); But it's not working ...

Comment: Got it working on their page.
In your case you have to do it like this: `$('.swiper-slide-active h3').html()`

Comment: Hey by the way, is there any way that I can force the slider to display the current month only... Like for instance today is May, and I'd like it to display default month on the slider (Which is May in this case) ...

Answer (score 0):

In these cases i usually add an active class to active node:

```
<div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>January</h3></div>
```

And i get current slider with active selector(with jQuery):

```
activeElement= $(".swiper-wrapper .active");
```

Now when i want to show next value, i hide activeElement and show next element and remove active class from activeElement and add to next.

```
activeElement.hide();
nextElemtn = activeElement.next();
nextElemtn.show();
nextElemtn.addClass("active");
```

or

```
activeElement.hide();
prevElemtn = activeElement.prev();
prevElemtn.show();
prevElemtn.addClass("active");
```

you can get html of active value like this:

```
activeElementHtml = activeElement.html()
```

there are some exceptions for when element is first and last child which you can access from index in jquery

```
indexElement = activeElement.index()
```

for example when index is 0 prev can not possible, or in last child is not possible which next call. you can get total number of elements with length jQuery

```
lengthElements = $(".swiper-wrapper").children('div').length;
```

you should add active class to first element like this:

```
<div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>January</h3></div>
```

Comment: That's good for other sliders, which don't already have an active indicator. Swiper has swiper-slide-active class.

Comment: Okay and how do I get the value of the active slide?? I've did like this:  $('#swiperNext').click(function(e)
   {
       var activeElement= $(".swiper-wrapper .active");
       console.log(activeElement);
   }); But I'm not getting the value of lets say "February"

Comment: use this: activeElementValue= $(".swiper-wrapper .active").html(); console.log(activeElementValue); });